# How to display default value of option in ModelChoiceField django when loading?

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create a ModelChoiceField using form

```
class Person(forms.Form):

    person =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id'), required=False)
    age = forms.IntegerField(min_value=18, max_value=99, required=False)
```

return as an html output is

```
<option value="1">Person object</option>
```

Now I want to display default value of ModelChoiceField by `name` or `id` when loading page. Ex:

```
<option value="7">David</option>
```

If user don't want it, they can select an another one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to change `__unicode__` method(or `__str__` if on python3) so it would return name of person object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str

```
class Person:
    ... # your fields
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Than you need to provide default value for you form field https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#default

```
person =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('id'), required=False, default=Person.objects.get(id=7))
```

Comment: You're welcome, also if this answer fixed your problem you should mark it as such(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow), so when people visit this question they will know that this is correct one.